# Factory Maintenance Schedule by Mileage or Years?

Tags: honda, maintenance, civic, scheduled-maintenance

I have a 2001 Civic with 65K miles. I have not done the 60K service yet, but the maintenance schedule also says that is the 3 year maintenance. Is the age of the car as important as the mileage when following the schedule? Should I have all the maintenance suggested through the 120k miles / 10 year maintenance?

Other than the work contained in the 60k/3yrs service, this would also include:

- replace brake fluid
- inspect idle speed
- replace transmission fluid
- replace timing belt, inspect water pump
- replace engine coolant

Answer (score 2):

You should do that maintenance every 3 years, or 60K miles, whichever comes first.  Some items wear based on usage, others deteriorate over time.

If you're not up to 120K miles or 10 years, I don't see that you'd NEED to do that part now.  However, it certainly wouldn't hurt the car to do so (might hurt your bank account though).